# How to prove that a simplicial complex is path-connected if connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If K consists of finite simplices and connected, it seems intuitively clear that any two 0-simplices can be connected by a path whose image is a collection of 0-simplices and 1-simplices.

But I can't rigorously construct such a path... Could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 4):

Prove and use the following two lemmas:

*Lemma*. A connected and locally path-connected<sup>$\dagger$</sup> space is path-connected.

> When a space is locally connected, the path components are open. So if $C$ is a path component, it's open, and its complement is a union of other path components, which are open so $C$ is closed too.

*Lemma*. A simplicial complex is locally path-connected.

> A simplicial complex is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k \times [0,\infty)^{n-k}$.

---

<sup>$\dagger$</sup> A space is locally path-connected when every point has a basis of path-connected neighborhoods.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for your hint!